# Titleize text with jq

Tags: bash, jq

How can I titleize text (capitalize each word) with `jq`?

Expected transformation: `"lorum ipsum"` → `"Lorum Ipsum"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a string you consider calling a word, you may uppercase its first character by converting it into an array (`./""`), modifying the first element (`first|=ascii_upcase`) and joining all elements back together (`add`) like so

```
./"" | first |= ascii_upcase | add
```

Similarly, given a string of words, split it into an array of words, apply the above to each element using `map` and join them back together. Depending on what you (or the input data requires you to) consider a word, splitting the string might differ. Given your input example (`"lorum ipsum"`), using a single space character as word separator will suffice. I'll set it in a variable (`--arg ws ' '`) and use it for splitting (`./$ws`) and joining (`join($ws)`):

```
echo '"lorum ipsum"' | jq --arg ws ' ' '
  
  ./$ws | map(
    
    ./"" | first |= ascii_upcase | add
    
  ) | join($ws)
  
'
```

Answer (score 1):

this may be achieved with `gsub`, `ascii_upcase`, and named capture groups:

```
$ echo '"lorum ipsum"' | jq 'gsub("(?<x>[A-z])(?<y>[A-z]+)"; "\(.x|ascii_upcase)\(.y)")'
"Lorum Ipsum"
```

Comment: Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nawk` `for` loop, `toupper`, `sub` and `substr` as below:

```
echo 'lorum ipsum' |  nawk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)sub(/./,toupper(substr($i,1,1)),$i)}1'
```